# Isomorphism in an SPA consuming a REST service

Tags: node.js, express, seo, isomorphism

I'm currently in the planning stages of a new project which is composed of a storefront, a highly reactive user dashboard, and the individual products being offered via the storefront being highly interactive mini-apps. We're trying to get away with making the entire platform a SPA and design the entire thing on a Flux architecture with React for the front-end views.

One issue, as with most SPAs, is SEO. I've prototyped an isomorphic solution based on the este.js dev stack. One issue is that our app consumes pretty much all of its data from a RESTful server, which is separate from the web server serving up the SPA. This means that the web server would need to fetch a considerable amount of data from the RESTful server, to isomorphically generate the HTML snapshot.

I've considered having a separate crawler process of my own crawl the entire storefront periodically and isomorphically generate HTML snapshots of the pages that could be served up when the web server encounters a search engine crawler. I'm not sure if this is a good approach though, as it would likely introduce additional maintenance and, frankly, seems a bit fragile. I could just have the web server isomorphically generate the HTML on the fly, but I fear bogging the server down for ordinary users as the server would be pulling considerable data from the REST API...

Is there a better way to handle such a case?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Yahoo's Fetchr, an open-source library that allows you to isomorphically hit your API.  It ties into Facebook's Flux architecture, so you need to have Stores, but at the very least you can glean some code and concepts from it.  If you're in the planning phase, you might even consider going with the Flux or Fluxible.

http://fluxible.io/guides/data-services.html

https://github.com/yahoo/fetchr